# How to get selected text from WPF Combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to get text from WPF ComboBox, when it will select but unable to get any text. Below are the codes which I have tried. If someone please help me to get text from ComboBox when I select different Content. please note that, ComboBox will load data from sql server which is working perfectly !

my XAML code is:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboID" TabIndex="27" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged="comboID_SelectionChanged"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="694,396,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"/>
```

below are my C# codes example which I have tried:

```
string str1 = comboID.SelectedItem.ToString();

string str2 = comboID.SelectedValue.ToString();

string str3 = comboID.Text;

ComboBoxItem cmb = comboID.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;

var myVal = sender as ComboBox;
string value = comboID.SelectedItem as string;
```

Comment: _Loaded from SQL server_ but how? What is the item type and what do you want to get?

Comment: Please post [a good, minimal, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows exactly what you have done, explain what you have tried, what happened when you tried it, and how that is different from what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: data are loading in the comboBox as string. like "One", "Two", "Three" etc.
and I want string like; string str = "Two";

Comment: Delete all your code and use proper DataBinding.

Comment: @logcat if items would be of string type, as you say, then `(string)SelectedItem` or even `SelectedItem.ToString()` would work.

Comment: When using SelectedItem.ToString();, in log I am getting  "System.Data.DataRowView", Instead of my string value from comboBox.

Comment: Please post the code where you are setting your `ComboBox` `ItemsSource` property. Also since you have set `SelectedValuePath` your event will get the value of whatever is in `Content` property.

Comment: here is the code to adding value in coboBox, and this code adding values perfectly but I am not sure the format of the value, if its like Content or Object or others !
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=myPC;Integrated Security=true;Connection Timeout=5;Database=myDB;");
            SqlDataAdapter sqlD = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ID from Seller ORDER BY ID", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sqlD.Fill(ds, "Seller");
            comboID.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            comboID.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ID"].ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead of yours for adding items in combobox:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection");

SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand();

SqlDataReader sdr = null;

conn.Open();
cmnd.Connection = conn;

String query = "Select ID from Seller ORDER BY ID";                
cmnd.CommandText = query;

sdr = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

while (sdr.Read())
{
   comboID.Items.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
}
```

Now you can use:

```
string str = comboExporterID.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple code to give you a rough idea.

My Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="350">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Select Item" x:Name="LblSelectNumber" MinWidth="50px" Margin="5"></Label>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboId" DisplayMemberPath="Number"
                  SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged="ComboID_OnSelectionChanged" MinWidth="100"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

My code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly List<MyItem> _items;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _items = new List<MyItem>
            {
                new MyItem{Content = "Test1",Number = "One"},
                new MyItem{Content = "Test2",Number = "Two"},
                new MyItem{Content = "Test3",Number = "Three"}
            };

        ComboId.ItemsSource = _items;
    }

    private void ComboID_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ComboId.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
}



public class MyItem
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Please observe the usage of `DisplayMemberPath` property in `ComboBox`

A simple suggestion. Please use **MVVM** pattern while creating your application as it will help you to maintain the solution in the long run. What ever I have done above can be achieved quite easily using MVVM pattern

Comment: yes its showing the value in MessageBox for me also. but as I wrote, I am unable to fetch the string value in any string variable like above.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code. Try this, should work

**`string s = comboID.text;`**

Answer (score 0):

Add the Tag property to the comboboxitems:

```
<Comboboxitem Tag="This Value"/>
```

Then

```
GetValue=ComboBoxName.SelectedItem.Tag.ToString()
```

GetValue will be "This Value" instead of the System.windows.combobox blah blah blah..